# Why nobody is whelmed?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, young-justice

Robin in *Young Justice* discussed people are either overwhelmed or underwhelmed but nobody is being whelmed.

Is this a reference to something else or any historic significance of the absence of whelmed?

Comment: Chastity: *I know you can be underwhelmed, and you can be overwhelmed, but can you ever just be, like, whelmed?* Bianca: *I think you can in Europe.*  From [*10 Things I Hate About You*](https://www.quotes.net/mquote/961319).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I don't remember that scene. Maybe rewatch time.

Comment: @AnkitSharma It's in reference to a throwaway joke from Season 1 of young justice. Robin (Dick Grayson) In general plays with language a lot in this series, this is one that just stuck.

Comment: Although this question is inspired by a TV series, it is not a question about TV, but the English language. As such, it is off topic here and on topic at English Language and Usage Stack Exchange.

Comment: similarly, why are people normally never said to be gruntled?

Comment: I am ebriated enough to parage your ept and scrutable analysis. It is truly gusting.

Comment: Inept to apt, not ept (alternative spellings diverged). Inebriated to sober, not ebriated (*inebrians* is the entire word, not a prefix + base, and can't be split that way). Gusting makes no sense there, unless you'd describe such analysis as tasteful. @RobertColumbia

Comment: I don't know I'm fairly appointed that this topic is finally being discussed. (I was getting tired of it being cussed for so long)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be an english language question

Comment: @DForck42 we have way many such questin on site

Comment: @Nij "Ept" is [also a word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ept) though.

Comment: In the sense that somebody decided it should be and started using it, yes...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I saw this question asked on the [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19430/why-do-people-say-over-and-underwhelmed-but-never-just-whelmed) (reproduced accepted answer below as a quote) which indicates that "Whelm" is simply no longer in use.

In terms of Young Justice, it's likely meant as a joke/throwaway line to draw attention to an oddity of language rather than anything majorly significant.

> Whelm is labeled as "archaic" in NOAD, as it has fallen out of use.
>   Left in its wake are the would-be superlative overwhelm (which, rather
>   than actually meaning "more than whelmed", has simply taken over its
>   parent's definition) and its opposite underwhelm.
>
> The only contact I've had with the word has been in the hymn The Solid
>   Rock:
>
> > His oath, his covenant, his blood support me in the whelming flood.

Comment: Indeed "underwhelmed" relies on the original meaning of "whelm" being forgotten. "Whelmed" basically means covered, buried or drowned. Adding "over-" to that is just reinforcing those meanings (in the sense of "covering over", not "too much"). "Underwhelm" *doesn't* give the desired result if "whelm" can be analyzed; it only works as an antonym.

Comment: @hobbs Similarly, a phrase like “my whelm was very much under” rely on not only the meaning of _whelm_ being forgotten, but even it’s word class.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whelm

**Whelm** is an olde Englyshe verb meaning "to cover" or "overturn". It has fallen out of use in modern linguistics.